# Como transformar uma string em float através do template do angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou utilizando o componente `agm-map` e preciso passar para as propriedades `[latitude]` e `[longitude]` as coordenadas. Estou recebendo esses valores em string, porém preciso converter em numérico.

Eu tentei algo como:

```
<agm-map 
     [mapTypeId]="'hybrid'"
     [latitude]="parseFloat(local.localLatitudeB)"
     [longitude]="parseFloat(local.localLongitudeB)"
     [zoom]="16"
     [disableDefaultUI]="false">

     ...
```

Porém eu recebo:

> _co.parseFloat is not a function

Esse é um exemplo de `localLongitudeB` que recebo do meu front, porém está em string: -47.410351923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi bem sua dificuldade, mas, você não consegue fazer o **parse** diretamente no Html, isso não existe, nem com **interpolações moustache {{}}** não consegue, `parseFloat` é uma função Javascript e por tanto tem que ser declarada em um arquivo Javascript, o que pode fazer é ter 2 variáveis, 1 variável recebe o valor em **string** como disse e em outra vc guarda o valor do parse e utiliza como quiser, como na propriedade no Html, um exemplo:

**TS:**

```
latitude: string = '-47.410351923';
latNumber: number = null;

ngOnInit() {
  this.latNumber = parseFloat(this.latitude);
  console.log(typeof this.latNumber)              // tipo do valor => number : -47.410351923
}
```

**Html:**

```
<agm-map 
 [mapTypeId]="'hybrid'"
 [latitude]="latNumber"                           <!-- valor aqui -->
 [longitude]="longNumber"
 [zoom]="16"
 [disableDefaultUI]="false">

 ...
```